# Check a string to see if all characters are hexadecimal values

Tags: c#

What is the most efficient way in C# 2.0 to check each character in a string and return true if they are all valid hexadecimal characters and false otherwise?

#### Example

```
void Test()
{
    OnlyHexInString("123ABC"); // Returns true
    OnlyHexInString("123def"); // Returns true
    OnlyHexInString("123g"); // Returns false
}

bool OnlyHexInString(string text)
{
    // Most efficient algorithm to check each digit in C# 2.0 goes here
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192446/rewrite-ishexstring-method-with-regex

Comment: Maybe you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-be/dotnet/api/system.uri.ishexdigit?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Uri_IsHexDigit_System_Char_

Comment: We also need to check even number of char. e.g. abc gets through but not even and abcd could be hex or just char. Not easy one to sort out.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
public bool OnlyHexInString(string test)
{
    // For C-style hex notation (0xFF) you can use @"\A\b(0[xX])?[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z"
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(test, @"\A\b[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z");
}
```

Comment: For speed, which the question implies, you would want to compile the regular expression instead of evaluating it continually.

Comment: Isn't using a regex at all for this overkill? One day I'll have to measure it, but I can't believe it would be faster than Jeremy Ruten's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223832/check-a-string-to-see-if-all-characters-are-hexadecimal-values#223854).

Comment: Indeed - quick testing (with the help of Jon Skeet's Micro Benchmark code) reveals that even using a pre-compiled regex, the straightforward technique outlined by Jeremy Ruten is about 5 times faster.

Comment: Programmer efficiency v. Program efficiency. As usual, the real answer is 'it depends'. Thx for the link @CMS.

Comment: Better answer is Jeremy Rutan's below.  It's super fast, and 10x more readable than the regex approach.  Add a small check for a `0x` prefix (and chop it off if needed), and on my system, I can loop ~100,000 in 32ms (averaged over 10 such runs).

Comment: To add, compare my above comment with ~148ms (100,000 loops averaged over 10 runs) for the regex approach.  Robert Bernstein's LINQ version of Jeremy's answer is about ~70ms.

Comment: Why `\A\b` instead of a simple `^`? Shouldn't the start of a string always be at a word boundary? Same question for `\b\Z` vs `$`.

Comment: For those who wonder if `\b` is redundant here please read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639718/anchors-in-net-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 89):

Something like this:

(I don't know C# so I'm not sure how to loop through the chars of a string.)

```
loop through the chars {
    bool is_hex_char = (current_char >= '0' && current_char <= '9') ||
                       (current_char >= 'a' && current_char <= 'f') ||
                       (current_char >= 'A' && current_char <= 'F');

    if (!is_hex_char) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

**Code for Logic Above**

```
private bool IsHex(IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    bool isHex; 
    foreach(var c in chars)
    {
        isHex = ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || 
                 (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || 
                 (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'));

        if(!isHex)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Avoiding regex in simple comparison checks like this one makes sense because regex can be very slow *and* may leak memory. If you want to use it, at least use a static compiled regex object.
See: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/regular-expression-performance-comparisons/

Comment: Please do not compare a regex engine with a hammer - it is a regular parser, and when used wisely helps achieve the desired result in cases where code change is not an option.

Comment: And if you want to make sure that the string can be parsed later to a byte array, add `&& chars.Count() % 2 == 0`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The point of the hammer quote is that you don't use it wisely -- you use it for everything. The quote means that when you have a specific tool, you invent solutions using that tool, even when it's wildly unsuited for the problem at hand. For example, using code roughly equivalent to `new Regex("(^|,)e", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(string.Join(",", someList)).Count == someList.Count` to check that every item in the list starts with an `e`.

Comment: Just a nit: Since the main purpose is to check whether the string is valid hex, I would suggest inverting the condition and using && so as to stop at the first invalid condition.

Answer (score 34):

You can do a [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the string to test if the string in its entirity is a hexadecimal number.

If it's a particularly long string, you could take it in chunks and loop through it.

```
// string hex = "bacg123"; Doesn't parse
// string hex = "bac123"; Parses
string hex = "bacg123";
long output;
long.TryParse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out output);
```

Answer (score 13):

What about just:

`bool isHex = text.All("0123456789abcdefABCDEF".Contains);`

This basically says: check if all chars in the `text` string do exist in the valid hex values string.

Which is the simplest still readable solution to me.

(don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`)

**EDIT:**
Just noticed that [`Enumerable.All()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.90).aspx) is only available since .NET 3.5.

Comment: My favourite so far. As my string was already uppercase, I went for text.ToUpper().All("0123456789ABCDEF".Contains) . Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I use `Int32.TryParse()` to do this.  [Here's the MSDN page on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Old, sorry to kick this, but I don't see why everyone chose the complicated options, this is the real, easy, correct and implemented in the framework way to do it: Int32.TryParse("AE0F", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, out myHexNumber);

Comment: @Roy there is a difference between "Are all these characters valid hex characters?" versus "Is this string parseable as hex AND fits into an Int32?" You make a good point, but is it safe to assuming OP is converting an Int32 hex value?

Comment: For sanity on both Int32 and UInt32, one could create a wrapper call to [U]Int32.TryParse, first checking the length of the passed string.  If the length is `10`, then there might be a `0x` that needs to be verified (to avoid an overflow if it's two extra digits).  Else, anything `> 8` would be too large for either value.  The framework can probably then handle signed vs. unsigned.  Repeat for Int16/UInt16, Int64/UInt64, and Byte/SByte.  One can probably even create short extension method stubs for these purposes to be extra clever.

Comment: In .Net 4+ the syntax requires culture: Integer.TryParse(potentialhex, Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, value)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a LINQ version of [yjerem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813/yjerem)'s solution above:

```
private static bool IsValidHexString(IEnumerable<char> hexString)
{
    return hexString.Select(currentCharacter =>
                (currentCharacter >= '0' && currentCharacter <= '9') ||
                (currentCharacter >= 'a' && currentCharacter <= 'f') ||
                (currentCharacter >= 'A' && currentCharacter <= 'F')).All(isHexCharacter => isHexCharacter);
}
```

Comment: Novel, and it beats the regex version easily.  But a raw while loop is still way faster than LINQ.

Comment: return !hexString.Any(c => !(c >= '0' && c <= '9') && !(c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') && !(c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'));

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld Or remove the double negation: `return hexString.All(c => (...))`.

Answer (score 5):

Posting a VB.NET version of [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223832/482691#223854), because I came here while looking for such a version.  Should be easy to convert it to C#.

```vb
''' <summary>
'''   Checks if a string contains ONLY hexadecimal digits.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="str">String to check.</param>
''' <returns>
'''   True if string is a hexadecimal number, False if otherwise.
''' </returns>
Public Function IsHex(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) Then _
        Return False

    Dim i As Int32, c As Char

    If str.IndexOf("0x") = 0 Then _
        str = str.Substring(2)

    While (i < str.Length)
        c = str.Chars(i)

        If Not (((c >= "0"c) AndAlso (c <= "9"c)) OrElse
                ((c >= "a"c) AndAlso (c <= "f"c)) OrElse
                ((c >= "A"c) AndAlso (c <= "F"c))) _
        Then
            Return False
        Else
            i += 1
        End If
    End While

    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

A regular expression is not very efficient at the best of times. The most efficient will be using a plain `for` loop to search through the characters of the string, and break on the first invalid one found.

However, it can be done very succinctly with [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
bool isHex = 
    myString.ToCharArray().Any(c => !"0123456789abcdefABCDEF".Contains(c));
```

I cannot vouch for the efficiency, since LINQ is LINQ, but Any() should have a pretty well-optimised compilation scheme.

Comment: I think using [`Enumerable.All()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.90).aspx) is a little bit more readable. See my answer. Also just found out that LinQ is only available since .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of performance the fastest is likely to simply enumerate the characters and do a simple comparison check.

```
bool OnlyHexInString(string text) {
  for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
    var current = text[i];
    if (!(Char.IsDigit(current) || (current >= 'a' && current <= 'f'))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

To truly know which method is fastest though you'll need to do some profiling.

Answer (score 3):

```
    //Another workaround, although RegularExpressions is the best solution
     boolean OnlyHexInString(String text)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
        if( !Uri.IsHexDigit(text.charAt(i)) )
          return false;
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: "RegularExpressions is the best solution" -_-

Answer (score 1):

In terms of *programmer time*, it's probably best to call your platform's string-to-integer parsing function (such as Java's *Integer.parseInt(str, base)*), and see if you get an exception.  If you want to write it yourself, and potentially be more time/space-efficient...

Most efficient I suppose would be a lookup table on each character.  You would have a 2^8 (or 2^16 for Unicode)-entry array of booleans, each of which would be *true* if it is a valid hex character, or *false* if not.  The code would look something like (in Java, sorry ;-):

```
boolean lut[256]={false,false,true,........}

boolean OnlyHexInString(String text)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    if(!lut[text.charAt(i)])
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I agree with Matt. You have to evaluate each character to see if it is hex character, and his test  to see if a character is hex is a simple lookup that involves a single test.  The trade off is that you need that 256 boolean array; exactly as Matt says time/space tradeoff.  The problem with the Integer.parseInt is that it'll probably fail if the string would produce an Int larger than MaxInt.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution without regular expressions is:

VB.NET:

```
Public Function IsHexString(value As String) As Boolean
    Dim hx As String = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    For Each c As Char In value.ToUpper
        If Not hx.Contains(c) Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Or in C#

```
public bool IsHexString(string value)
{
    string hx = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    foreach (char c in value.ToUpper()) {
        if (!hx.Contains(c))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this method:

```
public static bool IsHex(this char c)
{
  return   (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
           (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') ||
           (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with regular expressions, which are an efficient way of checking if a string matches a particular pattern.

A possible regular expression for a hex digit would be [A-Ha-h0-9]*, some implementations even have a specific code for hex digits, e.g. [[:xdigit:]]*.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't an answer for everything.  Something as simple as checking for a small range of characters in a string, and bugging out if a single character fails t match is going to be handled much faster using the loop scenario presented above n Jeremy Ruten's answer.  I just tested regex, the LINQ version of Jeremy's answer, and the raw loop, and the raw loop approach works out the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You can Extend string and char using someting like this:

```
    public static bool IsHex(this string value)
    {   return value.All(c => c.IsHex()); }

    public static bool IsHex(this char c)
    {
        c = Char.ToLower(c);
        if (Char.IsDigit(c) || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f'))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And this as C# extension method...

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsHexString(this string str)
    {
        foreach (var c in str)
        {
            var isHex = ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
                          (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') ||
                          (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'));

            if (!isHex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    //bonus, verify whether a string can be parsed as byte[]
    public static bool IsParseableToByteArray(this string str)
    {
        return IsHexString(str) && str.Length % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Use it like so...

```
if("08c9b54d1099e73d121c4200168f252e6e75d215969d253e074a9457d0401cc6".IsHexString())
{
    //returns true...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution to come around this issue. Check that the Request string is not null before executing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Length; i += 2)
  if (!byte.TryParse(string.Join("", Request.Skip(i).Take(2)), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out _)) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool HexInCardUID(string test)
        {
            if (test.Trim().Length != 14)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
                if (!Uri.IsHexDigit(Convert.ToChar(test.Substring(i, 1))))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }**strong text**
```

Comment: Added a small description will make this answer better for people visiting in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[`char.IsAsciiHexDigit(Char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isasciihexdigit?view=net-8.0) is available in .NET 7 and 8:

```
// true
bool isHex = "ABCDEF0123456789".All(char.IsAsciiHexDigit);

// false
bool isHex = "This is not a number.".All(char.IsAsciiHexDigit);
```

Answer (score -4):

Now, only

```
if (IsHex(text)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The question is about implementing this `IsHex` method. There is no such built-in method.

Comment: By the way, expressions of the form `if(test) {return true;} else {return false;}` are equivalent to simply `return test;`