# Char.IsHex() in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223832/check-a-string-to-see-if-all-characters-are-hexadecimal-values) what would be the best way to write a Char.IsHex() function in C#. So far I've got this but don't like it:

```
bool CharIsHex(char c) {
    c = Char.ToLower(c);
    return (Char.IsDigit(c) || c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f')
}
```

Comment: Are you allowing hex specifiers, such as the prefix '0x' or the suffix 'h' ?

Comment: What about System.Uri.IsHexDigit :-) http://tinyurl.com/6pavod

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223832/check-a-string-to-see-if-all-characters-are-hexadecimal-values#223854) to the question you linked to:

```
bool is_hex_char = (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
                   (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') ||
                   (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F');
```

Answer (score 19):

You can write it as an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static bool IsHex(this char c)
   {
      return   (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
               (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') ||
               (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F');
   }
}
```

This means you can then call it as though it were a member of `char`.

```
char c = 'A';

if (c.IsHex())
{
   Console.WriteLine("We have a hex char.");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Note that `Char.IsDigit()` returns `true` for many more code points than just the digits in the ASCII range 0x30 to 0x39.

For example the Thai digit characters that return `true` from Char.IsDigit(): '๐'  '๑'  '๒'  '๓'  '๔'  '๕'  '๖'  '๗'  '๘'  '๙'

Also there are the 'Full width' characters that `Char.IsDigit()` returns true for: `0xff10` through `0xff19`.  These glyphs look just like the ASCII characters `0x30-0x39`, so if you're going to accept them you should also probably accept `0xff21-0xff26` and `0xff41-0xff46` which look just like 'A'-'F' and 'a'-'f'.

If you're going to support digits that are outside of the ASCII range, your users might expect that you to support glyphs that correspond to Latin 'a'..'f' and 'A'..'F' that exist in other scripts outside of the ASCII range.

Personally, I think I'd stick with something more like:

```
        bool isHexChar = ('0' <= c) && (c <= '9') ||
                         ('a' <= c) && (c <= 'f') ||
                         ('A' <= c) && (c <= 'F');
```

Which I think would be potentially less surprising to people.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a .NET method:

```
char c = 'a';
System.Uri.IsHexDigit(c);
```

Comment: Yes! This has been there since the start of .net and is part of the core standard library.

Answer (score 3):

There's one more way to do it, using string comparison.

```
bool IsHex(char c)
{
    return "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef".IndexOf(c) != -1;
}
```

Comment: `char` is always a UTF-16 code unit in C#. Your example would not be encoding neutral in any case, since C# strings are similarly UTF-16.

Comment: @JohnColanduoni I removed wrong information from my answer

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
bool CharIsHex(char c) {
    c = Char.ToLower(c);
    return Char.IsDigit(c) || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f');
}
```

Comment: _Slight_ overhead added by the `Char.ToLower` call.  Way faster than calling the string version of `ToLower` on an entire input string, THEN checking.  But still faster, based on my quick benchmarks, to just loop an entire string and test for hex characters using a tight loop and checking for `a-f` as well as `A-F`.

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 6.0 / C# 10, the source code for `System.Uri.IsHexDigit(char)` is (unsurprisingly) still an exact equivalent to the accepted answer from over a decade ago. A nice reminder that simple solutions are often best.

If, however, you really want to use your own extension method, a concise, modern, and readable version using pattern matching and expression body syntax such as the following would be functionally equivalent.

```csharp
// add this to a public static extensions class
public static bool IsHexDigit(this char c) => c is >= '0' and <= '9' or >= 'a' and <= 'f' or >= 'A' and <= 'F';
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Char.IsAsciiHexDigit(Char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isasciihexdigit?view=net-8.0) is available in .NET 7 and 8.

Comment: Which uses a 64bit shift to reduce the number of operations and branching... https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2b015648dc114c168232f5e3ba1540ad24bb7895/src/libraries/Common/src/System/HexConverter.cs#L385

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions in an extension function:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsHex(this char c)
    {

        return (new Regex("[A-Fa-f0-9]").IsMatch(c.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: A regex seems pretty heavy-weight for a test as simple as this - and in particular creating a new regular expression each time is going to be  performance killer.

Comment: No!  Away with the regular expressions!  They're great when you're dealing with complex strings and the like, but testing a mere hexadecimal value for correctness is trivial and can be done with a small amount of code that is way faster than regex will ever be.