# How can I test whether a string contains only hex characters in C#?

Tags: c#, string, validation

I have a long string (8000 characters) that should contain only hexadecimal and newline characters.

What is the best way to validate / verify that the string does not contain invalid characters?

Valid characters are: 0 through 9 and A through F. Newlines should be acceptable.

I began with this code, but it does not work properly (i.e. fails to return false when a "G" is the first character):

```
public static bool VerifyHex(string _hex)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9A-F]+$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    return r.Match(_hex).Success;
}
```

Comment: Your `Regex` should be `static`.

Comment: Looks like a repost of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223832/check-a-string-to-see-if-all-characters-are-hexadecimal-values

Comment: Did you test how/why it doesn't work? Now we need to guess what's wrong here..

Comment: @Rudi: It is similar but mine must allow newlines.

Comment: @Sander Rijken: It fails to identify, for example, a "G" at the start of the string.

Comment: So when it starts with a G it succeeds?

Comment: @Sander Rijken: Yes, but SLaks identified the reason. The `Multiline` option was causing it to match based on lines that were correct. A "G" appearing on the first line was merely ignored. Because other lines matched, it reported true.

Comment: @JYelton, that isn't a giant change - add `\r\n` to the square brackets of *CMS*'s (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the [`Multiline` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Use multiline mode, where **^** and
>   **$** match the beginning and end of each line (instead of the beginning
>   and end of the input string).

Change it to

```
static readonly Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9A-F\r\n]+$");
public static bool VerifyHex(string _hex)
{
    return r.Match(_hex).Success;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this worked as needed. I was using the Multiline option incorrectly (much like using a screwdriver for a chisel, one achieves less-than-great results).

Answer (score 5):

Another option, if you fancy using LINQ instead of regular expressions:

```
public static bool IsHex(string text)
{
    return text.All(IsHexChar); 
}

private static bool IsHexCharOrNewLine(char c)
{
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
           (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') ||
           (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') ||
           c == '\n'; // You may want to test for \r as well
}
```

Or:

```
public static bool IsHex(string text)
{
    return text.All(c => "0123456789abcdefABCDEF\n".Contains(c)); 
}
```

I think a regex is probably a better option in this case, but I wanted to just mention LINQ for the sake of interest :)

Comment: I am using and liking LINQ more every day. This reads cleanly but would regex perform better?

Comment: @JYelton: I don't know - why don't you benchmark it with some real data and check? I'd expect the first version to run faster than the second, mind you.

Comment: I performance tested this compared to the Regular Expression solution, and this approach is ~3x faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are already some great answers but no one has mentioned using the built in parsing which seems to be the most straight forward way:

```
public bool IsHexString(string hexString)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    int output = 0;
    return Int32.TryParse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, provider, out output))
}
```

Comment: The strings I am testing are ~8000 characters, it would overflow Int32 unless broken into pieces.

Comment: @JYelton somehow I missed that in the question sorry.  Well at least this is a good conversion for anyone else that needs to do a lot less chars :)