# C# FormatException Unhandled when converting Hex to decimal

Tags: c#

So I am still learning C#, and i have a bit of a problem. I am making a very simple windows forms application, with two text boxes, input and Output, For conversions from hex to dec. Here is my code:

```
        string input = textBox1.Text;
        int Output = Convert.ToInt32(input, 16);
        textBox2.Text = Output.ToString();

        //Textbox1 is Input
        //Textbox2 is Output
```

Comment: I suspect your issue is `textBox1` is empty when the application first starts, and the convert fails. What is the value of `input` when you get your exception? Use the debugger to find out.

Answer (score 3):

There are potentially two exceptions you're going to run into here. First, is a FormatException like you described. This can occur if the input string isn't formatted correctly; say it contains a non hex character, a space, or something else. The other exception you will encounter is an overflow exception, when the hex from the first text box becomes a number too large for a 32 bit integer.

To handle the exceptions, you're going to need a try catch block. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx for more info on the try catch.

A better way of writing this with some error checking might look like something below:

```
string input = textBox1.Text;

try
{
    int Output = Convert.ToInt32(input, 16);
    textBox2.Text = Output.ToString();
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input string is not in the correct format.");
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input is too large for conversion.");
}

//Textbox1 is Input
//Textbox2 is Output
```

As Shar1er80 and Landepbs have pointed out, the code you provided won't error if your input is correct. It's your job as the programmer to validate that the input will not error. You can do an error check with a regular expression as Shar1er80 has suggested, but there are other ways as well. You will not only need to check that the input contains valid characters for conversion to hex, you also should check the length. Each Hex character can be one of 16 possible values (0-F). Putting two of them together yields 256 possible values, or exactly one byte. A 32 bit integer is 4 bytes, meaning your maximum length of valid input is 8 characters. Any more, and the integer will overflow.

You should also decide if you want to use a signed integer as you have or an unsigned integer. In signed integers, one bit is used for the sign, so the largest positive integer you can output is half what it would be for an unsigned integer. You can read more about integers and sign at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx.

Good luck learning C# and stick with it!

Comment: It's also possible for an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` to be thrown from `Convert.ToInt32()`, if the input is an empty string.  A `null` string value will be converted to `0`.

Comment: Rock on John. According to the documentation though, we should handle `ArgumentException` which I believe is the base class of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. OP, If you are using Visual Studio and hover over the `ToInt32` function call, Intellisense will pop up with the documentation as well as the list of exceptions the function could throw. I take the listed ones as ones you should handle most of the time in your code. This documentation is very reliable for framework functions, and somewhat less so for 3rd party code.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.  The declaration is as follows: `public class ArgumentOutOfRangeException : ArgumentException, ISerializable`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem?  This code looks good with one exception, HEX is limited to 0 - 9 and A - F.  I would suggest adding input validation for this.

EDITED:
Check this SO answer for validating hex input
[Check a string to see if all characters are hexadecimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223832/check-a-string-to-see-if-all-characters-are-hexadecimal-values)