# What would be a better way to filter out non-hexadecimal characters from a string?

Tags: c#, c++, ascii, boolean-logic

I just tried out PVS-Studio on my C# project and it pointed out this function that screens for valid hexadecimal characters.  Originally the logic allowed all characters, but after fixing it I can't shake the feeling that there is a better way to do this.

```
    string ValidHex()
    {
        string str = foo.Value;
        for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index++)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(str[index]) == false)
            {
                if ((str[index] >= 'A' && str[index] <= 'F') ||
                    (str[index] >= 'a' && str[index] <= 'f'))
                    continue;
                else
                    return "Invalid Hex value";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I know I can't improve the time complexity, but is there a less awkward way to screen these ASCII values?

Comment: I swear that I searched beforehand, thanks to whomever pointed this out.

Comment: side notes: 1- let the function return a boolean and not a string; 2- instead `if (something) continue else return "error";` use a more readable `if (!something) return "error";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to check for a string being a valid hex string would be to use a regular expression for hex and attempt to match it.

```
public bool OnlyHexInString(string test)
{
    // For C-style hex notation (0xFF) you can use @"\A\b(0[xX])?[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z"
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(test, @"\A\b[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z");
}
```

Read more here: [Check a string to see if all characters are hexadecimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223832/check-a-string-to-see-if-all-characters-are-hexadecimal-values)

Comment: A regular expression is overkill for something this straightforward.

Comment: The OP supplied a straight-forward solution and asked if there was a less awkward way to do it. I supplied a one-liner approach. :)

Comment: @PeteBecker Could you expand on why you call this "overkill"?  As I am not familiar with regular expressions, I now find myself reading about "statically compiled regex objects".

Comment: In C++ this would be done with `return test.find_first_not_of("0123456789ABCDEFabcdef") == string::npos;` It's a straightforward text search, no need for statically compiling regex objects or any other such juju.