# Anchors in .NET regular expressions

Tags: .net, regex

This is a question about the answer given in the question [Check a string to see if all characters are hexadecimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223857/112968).

The proposed regular expression is the following:

```
\A\b[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z
```

Now, `\A` and `\Z` seem to be the equivalent to `^` and `$` respectively. `\Z` behaves differently, in that it allows a newline after it when matching (this might or might not be intended).

What I don't understand is why the `\b` "match at word boundary" anchor is used. Isn't the beginning/end of a string always a word boundary?

Ultimately, the regex could be rewritten as `^[0-9a-fA-F]$` with the same behavior (ignoring the trailing `\n` issue). Am I missing something? Is using `\b` required for some weird edge case?

Test cases:

```
123ABC -> true
123def -> Returns true
123g -> Returns false
```

Comment: Yeah I can't think of anything that the `\b` is accomplishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**word boundary `\b`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) matches between non-word and word characters, and also at the start of the string if the first character is a word character, and at the end if the last character is a word character.

Thus, `\A\b[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z` is equal to `\A[0-9a-fA-F]+\Z` because *all the characters in the string must be word characters (`[0-9]` digits or `[a-fA-F]` letters) for the pattern to match it*.

It would be a different story in this case: `\A\b[0-9a-fA-F-]+\b\Z` that would only match strings with word characters at the beginning and end.

Use `\z` to match a whole string, with no `\n` allowed at the end.